# What would be a reasonable configuration for a pizza store?

Tags: expresso-store, ecommerce

I'm wondering what would be the best implementation for a pizza store. The workflow would be:

- User adds a pizza (product) to their cart.
- User is able to add a la carte toppings to their pizza, each of which increases the price slightly.

I'm assuming some combination of price modifiers would do the trick, but I'm not sure if you are able to add multiple modifiers to a single product?

Any thoughts or suggestions would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can definitely add multiple modifiers to each product. The customer will have to select one option from each group before they can add the product to their cart. That will work fine for things like the base, and you can have yes/no options for each custom topping.

It's hard to anticipate in advance what you need though, so it's probably best if you have a go at setting it up and let us know if and where you get stuck.

Comment: Giving the user the ability to choose 3 toppings (3 options) with each option dropdown having the same items seems like a feasible solution. Thanks!

Comment: Yes that would work well. You could even add a price modifier for extra toppings after the first three, or for premium toppings.

Answer (score 0):

I’m pretty sure you can only use one modifier for a product when adding it to your Store. You can add multiple modifiers in the back end, but only pick one from a select type menu on the front end. This is because modifiers are generally colour or size related.

I would investigate adding each topping as a product of it’s own, then either creating relationships or category groups for finer control over which toppings go with which pizza, if necessary. Then you can add small prices to toppings and apply discounts at volume.

Obviously you’re going to have to be canny when a pizza is selected. But there’s nothing stopping you from displaying the chosen pizza at the checkout and displaying the related topping products immediately underneath so the customer can build their pizza.

Hope that’s useful.